# How to delete characters till the end after digits

Tags: vim

I have input as below

```
1sum
2subtract
3multipy
4divide
...
```

Expected output:

```
1
2
3
4
...
```

I tried `%s/[0-9].*//g`
But it is deleting digits also
I want to retain digits..pls help

Answer (score 1):

How about this one:

```
:%s/\([0-9]\).*/\1 /g
```

Answer (score 1):

You're matching everything *including* the digits themselves.

An easy way to accomplish what you're after is to use `\D` to match the first non-digit character and then delete to the end of the line:

```
:%s/\D.*//
```

Note that `\D` is the same as `[^0-9]` which is any character *except* for a digit, so adding the caret to your original expression would have worked as well:

```
:%s/[^0-9].*//
```

You don't need the `/g` at the end (even though it doesn't hurt), since you can have at most one match per line, since the match will always consume until the end of the line.

Comment: `:%s/.\zs.*//g`

Comment: @SergioAraujo Yeah I'd definitely use `\zs` if I wanted to match the digits, i.e. `:%s/[0-9]*\zs.*//`. I wanted to get a solution that would work for numbers with 2 or more digits and also wouldn't produce false positives (keeping a non-digit) for lines without digits...